# c w movement up to next word instead of end of word

Tags: evil

In vi, <kbd>c w</kbd> stops at the end of the current word (that movement is normally <kbd>e</kbd>, as in <kbd>c e</kbd>). This is different from <kbd>w</kbd> alone or <kbd>d w</kbd>, which go up to the beginning of the next word.

A popular Vim configuration causes <kbd>c w</kbd> to do work like other `w` commands, where the "word" movement takes you UP TO the next word. Consuming any whitespace.

How do I make <kbd>c w</kbd> work in evil as it does in this Vim configuration?

Evil: 1.14.0
Emacs: 27.1

Comment: I cannot reproduce that `cw` behavior in Vim at all. Do you have a complete repro?

Comment: You must have rebound `cw` to `dwi` or `caw` in Vim. It's suggested in the manual, but it's not the default.

Comment: Wow, that's wild. I just tried on vim without my vimrc, and you're right. Didn't expect that to be part of my local config! Thanks guys, and thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `C-h v` `evil-want-change-word-to-end` `RET`, then `customize` that variable from `t` to `nil`.

Reference:

> evil-want-change-word-to-end is a variable defined in ‘evil-vars.el’.
> Its value is t
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> Documentation: Whether ‘cw’ behaves like ‘ce’.

Comment: no way. They really thought of everything. Thank you Terry.

Comment: @hraban Indeed. `evil` is one of the best IMO. :-)